# Comparing all If statements first BEFORE displaying an output

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, radio-button, switch-statement

I thought I had the logic figured out; However, the output I am getting is the first IF statement that is found to be true. In order to go through the logic first and find the correct output BEFORE an alert box is displayed, do I need to use a switch statement?

If so, what does that look like for this? I have been doing my due diligence and cannot seem to figure out how a switch statement applies to my situation.

```js
    function get_recommendation() {
  var ES = "Everyday Solutions";
  var IL = "ILAB";
  var SP = "Spark";
  var IT = "IT Innovation";

  $(document).ready(function() {
    //If Opco is checked, and both ES are checked yes
    if (($('input[name="opco"]:checked').length > 0) && ($('#Yes1').is(':checked')) && ($('#Yes2').is(':checked'))) {
 var case1 = alert("Primary Recommendation: " + ES + "\n Secondary Recommendation: " + IL + " or " + SP);
    }
    //If Opco is checked, both ES are checked yes, and ILAB is checked yes
    if (($('input[name="opco"]:checked').length > 0) && ($('#Yes1').is(':checked')) && ($('#Yes2').is(':checked')) && ($('#Yes3').is(':checked'))) {
 var case2 = alert("Primary Recommendation: " + ES + "\n Secondary Recommendation: " + IL);
    }
    //If Opco is checked, both ES are checked yes, ILAB is checked no, and Spark is checked yes
    if (($('input[name="opco"]:checked').length > 0) && ($('#Yes1').is(':checked')) && ($('#Yes2').is(':checked')) && ($('#No3').is(':checked')) && ($('#Yes4').is(':checked'))) {
 var case3 = alert("Primary Recommendation: " + ES + "\n Secondary Recommendation: " + SP);
    }
    //If Opco is checked, both ES are checked yes, ILAB is checked yes, and Spark is checked yes
    if (($('input[name="opco"]:checked').length > 0) && ($('#Yes1').is(':checked')) && ($('#Yes2').is(':checked')) && ($('#Yes3').is(':checked')) && ($('#Yes4').is(':checked'))) {
 var case4 = alert("Primary Recommendation: " + ES + "\n Secondary Recommendation: " + IL + " or " + SP);
    }
    //If Opco is checked, both ES are checked no, and ILAB is checked yes
    if (($('input[name="opco"]:checked').length > 0) && ($('#No1').is(':checked')) && ($('#No2').is(':checked')) && ($('#Yes3').is(':checked'))){
 var case5 = alert("Primary Recommendation: " + IL + "\n Secondary Recommendation: " + SP);
    }
    //If Opco is checked, both ES are checked no, ILAB is checked yes, and Spark is checked yes
    if (($('input[name="opco"]:checked').length > 0) && ($('#No1').is(':checked')) && ($('#No2').is(':checked')) && ($('#Yes3').is(':checked')) && ($('#Yes4').is(':checked'))){
 var case6 = alert("Primary Recommendation: " + IL + " or " + SP);
    }
    //If Opco is checked, both ES are checked no, Spark is checked yes
    if (($('input[name="opco"]:checked').length > 0) && ($('#No1').is(':checked')) && ($('#No2').is(':checked')) && ($('#Yes4').is(':checked'))){
 var case7 = alert("Primary Recommendation: " + SP);
    }
    //If IT is checked yes
    if ($('#Yes5').is(':checked')) {
        var case8 = alert("Primary Recommendation: " + IT);
    }

  });

}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!---------------------------------------------------------Operating Company Question----------------------------------->
<form name="operatingCompany">
  <h3>What Operating Company Are You Employeed With?</h3>
  <input type="radio" name="opco" id="GPC" value="GPC">GPC</br>
  <input type="radio" name="opco" id="APC" value="APC">APC</br>
  <input type="radio" name="opco" id="MPC" value="MPC">MPC</br>
  <input type="radio" name="opco" id="Gulf" value="Gulf">Gulf</br>
  <input type="radio" name="opco" id="SCS" value="SCS">SCS</br>
  </br>

  <input type="button" value="Display User Selection" onclick=get_opco() />
</form>

<p id="opco_result"> </p>
</br>


<!---------------------------------------------------------Prototyped Question----------------------------------->
<form name="prototyped">
  <h3>Has the innovation been prototyped?</h3>
  <input type="radio" name="prototyped" id="Yes1" value="Yes">Yes</br>
  <input type="radio" name="prototyped" id="No1" value="No">No</br>
  </br>

  <input type="button" value="Display User Selection" onclick=get_prototype() />
</form>

<p id="prototyped_result"> </p>
</br>

<!--------------------------------------------------------Adopted or Tested Question---------------------------->
<form name="adopted_tested">
  <h3>Has the innovation been adobpted or tested?</h3>
  <input type="radio" name="adopt" id="Yes2" value="Yes">Yes</br>
  <input type="radio" name="adopt" id="No2" value="No">No</br>
  </br>

  <input type="button" value="Display User Selection" onclick=get_adopt_test() />
</form>

<p id="adopted_tested_result"> </p>
</br>

<!------------------------------------------------------Can it make money Question------------------------------->
<form name="makeMoney">
  <h3>Is this a product or service that can make money?</h3>
  <input type="radio" name="money" id="Yes3" value="Yes">Yes</br>
  <input type="radio" name="money" id="No3" value="No">No</br>
  </br>

  <input type="button" value="Display User Selection" onclick=get_money() />
</form>

<p id="makeMoney_result"> </p>
</br>

<!---------------------------------------------------Alabama Power Specific Questions----------------------------->
<form name="alabamaPower">
  <h3>Does your innovative idea help Alabama Power improve safety, grow revenue, reduce cost, or increase operational efficiency?</h3>
  <input type="radio" name="apc" id="Yes4" value="Yes">Yes</br>
  <input type="radio" name="apc" id="No4" value="No">No</br>
  </br>

  <input type="button" value="Display User Selection" onclick=get_alabamaPower() />
</form>

<p id="alabamaPower_result"> </p>
</br>
<!------------------------------------------------Explanation to prior question----------------------------------->
<h3>If yes, please explain</h3>
<textarea id="alabamaPower" rows="8" cols="50">
    
    </textarea> </br>
</br>

<input type="button" value="Display User Input" onclick=textareacapture() />

<p id="result"> </p>
</br>

<!------------------------------------------------IT Specific Question------------------------------------------->
<form name="innovativeTechnology">
  <h3>Is your innovation an innovative technology or process that boosts the company's productivity or brings additional value from a vendor relationship?</h3>
  <input type="radio" name="innovative" id="Yes5" value="Yes">Yes</br>
  <input type="radio" name="innovative" id="No5" value="No">No</br>
  </br>

  <input type="button" value="Display User Selection" onclick=get_innovative() />
</form>

<p id="innovativeTechnology_result"> </p>
</br>

<input type="button" value="Submit Form" onclick=get_recommendation() />
```

Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: Why do you keep checking the same thing `if ($('input[name="opco"]:checked').length > 0)` over and over? Do it once and put everything else inside that.

Comment: you should assign the alert message to a variable in each `if` block. Then you can call alert with that message once at the end.

Comment: And instead of nesting `if` blocks, use `&&`. `if (x) if (y) if (z) ...` should be `if (x && y && z) ...`

Comment: You also have lots more duplication than just the first `if`. If you have `if (x) if (y) {action 1}` followed by `if (x) if (y) if (z) {action 2}` you should combine them into `if (x && y) { action 1; if (z) { action 2 } }`

Comment: But the cases are related. "If Opco is checked, and both ES are checked yes" and "//If Opco is checked, both ES are checked yes, and ILAB is checked yes" both share the same first 3 checks, so you should just do them once, then check ILAB inside that. And then the `ILAB is checked no` case can be the `else` block for that, instead of having to repeat all the tests. The structure should mirror the logic.

Comment: But the important thing is my earlier comment: set a variable with the alert message, then alert at the end instead of doing it in each if block. Then you won't get multiple alerts.

Comment: Also, there's no need to use `$(document).ready`. `check_recommendation()` is called when the user clicks, and they can't do that until the document is ready.

Comment: Thank you very much @Barmar! I have edited my post with some of your pointers. Now that I have set variables for the alerts, how do I go about displaying the correct alert message depending on which IF is true? Is this where your pointer about duplicates comes into play?

Comment: You should be setting the SAME variable. `message = "Primary Recommendation: " + ES + "\n Secondary Recommendation: " + IL + " or " + SP`. Then at the end you do `alert(message)`

Comment: It works! Thanks a lot @Barmar!

Comment: Now time to implement more of your suggestions!

Answer (score 0):

You should be setting a single variable, not lots of different variables. And don't call `alert()` when you're setting the variable.

```
var message;

if ($('input[name="opco"]:checked').length > 0) {
    if ($('#Yes1').is(':checked') && $('#Yes2').is(':checked')) {
        message = "Primary Recommendation: " + ES + "\n Secondary Recommendation: " + IL + " or " + SP;
    }
    //If Opco is checked, both ES are checked yes, and ILAB is checked yes
    if ($('#Yes1').is(':checked') && $('#Yes2').is(':checked') && $('#Yes3').is(':checked')) {
        message = "Primary Recommendation: " + ES + "\n Secondary Recommendation: " + IL;
    }
    //If Opco is checked, both ES are checked yes, ILAB is checked no, and Spark is checked yes
    if ($('#Yes1').is(':checked') && $('#Yes2').is(':checked') && $('#No3').is(':checked') && $('#Yes4').is(':checked')) {
        message = "Primary Recommendation: " + ES + "\n Secondary Recommendation: " + SP;
    }
    //If Opco is checked, both ES are checked yes, ILAB is checked yes, and Spark is checked yes
    if ($('#Yes1').is(':checked') && $('#Yes2').is(':checked') && $('#Yes3').is(':checked') && $('#Yes4').is(':checked')) {
        message = "Primary Recommendation: " + ES + "\n Secondary Recommendation: " + IL + " or " + SP;
    }
    //If Opco is checked, both ES are checked no, and ILAB is checked yes
    if ($('#No1').is(':checked') && $('#No2').is(':checked') && $('#Yes3').is(':checked')) {
        message "Primary Recommendation: " + IL + "\n Secondary Recommendation: " + SP;
    }
    //If Opco is checked, both ES are checked no, ILAB is checked yes, and Spark is checked yes
    if ($('#No1').is(':checked') && $('#No2').is(':checked') && $('#Yes3').is(':checked') && $('#Yes4').is(':checked')) {
        message = "Primary Recommendation: " + IL + " or " + SP;
    }
    //If Opco is checked, both ES are checked no, Spark is checked yes
    if ($('#No1').is(':checked') && $('#No2').is(':checked') && $('#Yes4').is(':checked')) {
        message = "Primary Recommendation: " + SP;
    }
}
//If IT is checked yes
if ($('#Yes5').is(':checked')) {
    message = "Primary Recommendation: " + IT;
}

if (message) {
    alert(message);
}
```